# Getter and Setter of a variable with different type Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, design-patterns, swift4

I want **selectedDate** setter of type **Date** and getter to be of type **String**.

```
var selectedDate: Any? {
    get {
        //will return String
        return DateTimeUtils.sharedInstance.formatFancyDate(date: self.selectedDate as! Date)
    }
    set(newValue) {
        //will Set Date
        self.selectedDate =  DateTimeUtils.sharedInstance.dateFromStr(dateStr:newValue as! String)
    }
}
```

I know there are work-arounds but I would like to know if it can be done with Setters and Getters.

Comment: Apart from the question your code doesn't work anyway. The setter causes an infinite loop (and then a crash)

Comment: This sounds like a job for a function or extension of the Date class, not a getter and setter.

Comment: This would be a horrible idea. There are very easy ways to just convert one of them (`String` / `Date`) to another one.

Comment: @nayem Just want to know is anything like this possible i.e. variable with this property. Any ways thanks :)

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/different-types-for-getter-and-setter/6670

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s a good idea to have getter and setter with different types. It will be impossible for others or yourself to understand in a few months. If you need an easy access to Date as a string create an extension. I think this will be a better idea.